# Multiple Ajax Request when refetching Events from fullcalendar.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have the problem: hen i refetch the events from fullcalendar after i did the ajax request for inserting the event, he executes the ajax request multiple times. So the same event is twice or more in the database. Why that? Thanks!

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
....
                    //alert(date.format());
     $('#btnYesNew').click(function(){
                            var startTimeParam = 'startTime=' + date.format() + "%20" + $('#startTime').val();
                            var endTimeParam = 'endTime=' + date.format() + "%20" + $('#endTime').val();
                            var purposeParam = 'purpose='+ $('#zweck').val();
                            var carIdParam = 'carId=' + $('#auto').val();
                            var departmentIdParam = 'departmentId=' + $('#abteilung').val();

                            if (view.name != 'month'){
                                startTimeParam = 'startTime=' + date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "%20" + $('#startTime').val();
                                endTimeParam = 'endTime=' +date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "%20" + $('#endTime').val();

                            }

                            var uri = startTimeParam + "&" + endTimeParam + "&" + purposeParam + "&" + carIdParam + "&" + departmentIdParam;

                            // Add Event to database
                            $.get( "kfz-buchung-ajax-rent-add?" + uri, function( data ) {

                            })
                                    .done(function(data){
                                        $('#myModalNew').modal('hide');
                                    })

                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
                        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just used .off() before .click()